# Check if a user is in a group in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a server running where I use PHP to run a Bash script to verify certain information of a user. For example, I have a webhosting server set up, and in order to be able to add another domain to their account I want to verify if the user is actually a member of the `customers` group. What would be the best way to do this in Bash?

Comment: I know that this answer is old, but note that the root user should still be considered as allowed even if technically not inside every group of the planet. Maybe relevant if you may want to clarify if this should be explicitly excluded or not. Since I assumed that yes, it's nice to include this corner-case. So I hope my answer would give a wider and safer solution. If not, sorry.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
username=ANY_USERNAME
if getent group customers | grep -qw "$username"; then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

or

```
username=ANY_USERNAME
if groups $username | grep -qw 'customers'; then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

Comment: should `YOUR_OWN_USERNAME` actually be my own username, or could it just as well be any other existing username on the system? also, isn't there a way to formulate this as an if statement in bash script instead of php? I am running a bash script that checks if the user exists, and i'd like the same script to check if the user is in the 'customers' group as well.

Comment: Sorry, rewriten in bash ;) You can use any user_name from the system

Comment: for some reason this returns false every time. I also tried removing the `\b` on either side of the group name since I didn't know what it does, but that gave me the same result.

Comment: `\b` are word boundaries. The script have been tested successfully for me

Comment: This script has a bug in it! If the username is ``customers`` but it does not belong to ``customers`` group your script will still return true!

Comment: This is a false assumption, just tested it right now, return "false"

Comment: I finally got it to work. There indeed wasn't any problem with your code, I still used an old setting in the php script that called the bash script. This solution works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @sputnick ``echo 'customers : test1 test2 test3' | grep &>/dev/null '\bcustomers\b' && echo 'true' || echo 'false'`` returns true, so you're wrong. This script is buggy.

Comment: We don't have the same output on our distros. I use archlinux and the same behaviour have been saw on debian likes distro.

Comment: ...There's not the username at the line start.

Comment: Username appears in the groups command output at the output beginning, before a ```:```. This can be avoid by using ```id -Gn``` instead. Also, The word boundary ```\b``` can be avoid by using -w flag in grep, and the output redirection to ```/dev/null``` can be removed by using ```-q``` to specify silent check: grep will only return success or failure exit code to the shell this way.

Comment: how the hell there's no built in command for this... that's such a common task!!! :~(

Comment: This is flawed. Group/user names can contain `-` and this character (as far as `-b` is concerned) does separate words. `\bcustomers\b` matches `non-customers` or `customers-data`.

Comment: Groups may contain almost any characters a filename could contain. Including spaces, backslashes etc etc. Moreover, `getent group` may not show group members of NIS groups.

Comment: The `groups` command will return the group, even if the group was newly added and the user has not re-logged again to take its new membership into account.

Answer (score 58):

```
if id -nG "$USER" | grep -qw "$GROUP"; then
    echo $USER belongs to $GROUP
else
    echo $USER does not belong to $GROUP
fi
```

Explanation:

1. `id -nG $USER` shows the group names a user belongs to.
2. `grep -qw $GROUP` checks silently if $GROUP as a whole word is present in the input.

Comment: `grep -qw` doesn't work as expected for group names with `-` character. `systemd-journal` for example, matches `journal` or `systemd`.

Comment: Unfortunately, and contrary to `id` alone, `id -nG` will return the group, even if the group was newly added and the user has not re-logged again to take its new membership into account

Answer (score 28):

A slightly more error-proof method to check for group membership using zero char delimited fixed string grep.

```
if id -nGz "$USER" | grep -qzxF "$GROUP"
then
    echo User \`$USER\' belongs to group \`$GROUP\'
else
    echo User \`$USER\' does not belong to group \`$GROUP\'
fi
```

or using long opts

```
if id --name --groups --zero "$USER" | 
   grep --quiet --null-data --line-regexp --fixed-strings "$GROUP"
then
    echo User \`$USER\' belongs to group \`$GROUP\'
else
    echo User \`$USER\' does not belong to group \`$GROUP\'
fi
```

Comment: This one works even when groups might contain non-word characters (such as "-")

Comment: Note: this does not work with anything that uses Busybox (such as Alpine Linux).

Comment: This one may cause problems if you have two groups with similar names, eg. `sales` and `salessupport`. Asking about `sales` with match both.

Comment: @ralphbolton No, the problem you described won't happen. `-x` ensures that `sales` matches *only* exactly that and not `salessupport`.

Answer (score 7):

For all those [golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) fans out there:

```
ingroup(){ [[ " `id -Gn $2` " == *" $1 "* ]]; }
```

Usage: `ingroup group [user]`

Example:

```
if ingroup video; then
  echo 'Enjoy the show!'
fi
```

TL;DR The point is I have taken advantage of the built in [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) in order to find the substring.

Edit: Thanks to [@Anthony Geoghegan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1640661/anthony-geoghegan) for the `id -Gn` tip.

Comment: My own answer goes in the opposite direction (portability, verbosity, and readability) but I love the brevity and cleverness of this answer. To avoid worrying about the output of the `groups` command, you could replace it with the more predictable (and portable) `id -Gn`. It's also one character shorter. :)

Comment: Great answer in terms of real world usage. This check is safe, portable, and efficient, though you might want to use `[[ " $(id -Gn -- "$2") " == *" $1 "* ]]` to protect against non-usernames in `$2`. In terms of golf, it isn't that great. `id -Gnz $2|grep -qxz $1` would be 10 bytes shorter.

Comment: And yet there's space to grow! If you're using `set -u` in your shell scripts, this command will fail if you don't set the (supposedly optional) user parameter. We use POSIX parameter expansion to fix this oversight: `[[ " \`id -Gn ${2-}\` " == *" $1 "* ]]`.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is probably old thread but just in case this also works well:

```
id -Gn "username"|grep -c "groupname"
```

if any number > 0 is returned then user is a member of that group.

Comment: This malfunctions if you have two groups with similar names (eg. `sales` and `salessupport`)

Answer (score 6):

You could use
`groups $username_here | grep -q '\busergroup\b'`

The exitcode will be 0 if a match was found, 1 if no match was found.

```
user_in_group()
{
    groups $1 | grep -q "\b$2\b"
}
```

you could use this function as `user_in_group userfoo groupbar`

Comment: Why ```echo $?```? A shell function returns the exit code from the last executed command automatically. Also, the &>/dev/null can be avoided by using ```-q``` in grep.

Comment: You're right, thanks! I edited the code in my post. I actually didn't know about the `-q` option.

Comment: See [my answer to this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29557400/4161438) to see how to avoid the ```\b``` too.

Answer (score 5):

Using the zero delimiter to split by lines:

```
id -nGz user | tr '\0' '\n' | grep '^group$'
```

Comment: This one seems to work with all weird permutations of groups with `-` in them, groups with similar names etc. To use the GROUP variable like other answers, you can write it like this `id -nGz user | tr '\0' '\n' | grep '^'${GROUP}'$'` and can get rid of the output (to use just the return code, `$?`) by using `grep -q`.

Answer (score 2):

A while ago, I wrote a shell function to check if a user is a member of a group. To maximise portability, I wanted it be POSIX-compatible (while this question is tagged as `bash`, this function will still work). For performance, I wanted to use builtin shell features as much as possible: the only external command it uses is [`id`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/id.html), the POSIX-standardised utility for getting data about a user’s identity.

```sh
is_in_group()
{
  groupname="$1"
  # The second argument is optional -- defaults to current user.
  current_user="$(id -un)"
  user="${2:-$current_user}"
  for group in $(id -Gn "$user") ; do
    if [ "$group" = "$groupname" ]; then
      return 0
    fi
  done
  # If it reaches this point, the user is not in the group.
  return 1
}
```

Example usage to test both positive and negative cases – and ensure it handles a non-existent username gracefully:

```sh
g=mail
userlist="anthony postfix xxx"
for u in $userlist; do
  if is_in_group "$g" "$u"; then
    printf "%s is in ‘%s’\n" "$u" "$g"
  else
    printf "%s is NOT in ‘%s’\n" "$u" "$g"
  fi
done
```

Running the above command prints the following output:

```
anthony is NOT in ‘mail’
postfix is in ‘mail’
id: ‘xxx’: no such user
xxx is NOT in ‘mail’
```

---

It hasn’t been tested for the case where a group or user has a space or other unusual characters in their name but some research shows that such names are not legal: the POSIX Base Definition for [Group Name](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_190) states that

> To be portable across conforming systems, the value is composed of
>   characters from the portable filename character set.

The [Portable Filename Character Set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282) is specified as the alphanumeric characters, A-Z, a-z, 0-9 along with the period, underscore, and hyphen-minus characters.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an another answer:

```
username='myuser'
if grep -q -E "^customers:.*[:,]$username(,.*|\b)" /etc/group; then
    echo 'true'
else
    echo 'false'
fi
```

As reported by `sputnick` the output of the `groups` command may depend on your OS.
I am not sure how this code is going to perform, but most probably it will do better.

Comment: Works if /etc/group content is complete. Look out for setups where group data is served up or supplemented from another source (ldap, yp). See `nsswitch.conf(5)`. On those systems you might be stuck with the output of the `groups(1)` command.

Comment: @sjnarv: In some case (depending on the source), `getent group` piped into the grep might also work... Depends on the auth data source though...

Answer (score 0):

```
username='myuser'
if groups "$username" | grep -q -E ' customers(\s|$)'; then
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo 'no'
fi
```

I have to clear one thing:
`groups` will probably return something like this:

```
myuser : cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev fuse
```

But there is one cornercase when your user is named `customers`:

```
customers : cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev fuse
```

For example, `\bcustomers\b` pattern is going to find the username, not the group. So you have to make sure that it is not the first word in the output.

Also, another good regexp is:

```
grep -q ' customers\b'
```

Comment: What about if customers is also a username ? Your command will fails.

Comment: @sputnick it wont, because there's no space before username

Comment: Tested with the bug I discussed before : `groups sputnick | grep -q -E ' sputnick(\s|$)'` This return false and I'm in my own group

Comment: @sputnick so are you confirming that the script works or what? If you're in your own group and you're checking for the same named group, then the output is correct

Comment: ``echo 'customers : test1 test2 test3' | grep -q -E ' customers(\s|$)' && echo 'yes' || echo 'false'`` returns false, which is right

Comment: Note that this does not take in consideration the root user since it's not a real permission checking.

Answer (score 0):

My version not relying on grep.

First parameter (mandatory): group
Second parameter (optional, defaults to current user)

```
isInGroup(){
   group="$1"
   user="${2:-$(whoami)}"
   ret=false 
   for x in $(groups "$user" |sed "s/.*://g")
   do [[ "$x" == "$group" ]] && { ret=true ; break ; }
   done
   eval "$ret"
}
```

Comment: You have forgotten to pass the `$user` to the `groups` command

Answer (score 0):

Bash single line:

```
[[ " $(groups) " =~ ' spark ' ]] && echo 'Is in group'
```

Bash multi line:

```
if [[ " $(groups) " =~ ' spark ' ]]; then
    echo 'Is in group'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine.

### First the long version

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 [-v] user group"
  echo ""
  echo "  -v verbose. Outputs a sentence for humans."
  echo ""
  echo "Example:"
  echo ""
  echo "  ingroup wilma sudo && echo Wilma has superpowers"
  exit 2
fi

if [[ "$1" == "-v" ]]
then
  verbose=1
  shift
fi

user=$1
grp=$2
# Get groups output
grps=$(groups $user)
# Create a regexp. Note that we must create the regexp in a var
# because it's the only way to allow for spaces in the regexp.
# Strangely we provide this var unquoted when using it; even 
# though it has spaces.
re="^.*:.* $2 "
if [[ "$grps" =~ $re ]]
then
  [[ -n "$verbose" ]] && echo "$user is in group $grp"
  # Success error code
  exit 0
else
  [[ -n "$verbose" ]] && echo "$user is not in group $grp"
  # Fail error code
  exit 1
fi
```

### Want a shorter version as a function?

```sh
ingroup() {
  re="^.*:.* $2 "
  [[ "$(groups $1) " =~ $re ]] || return 1
}
```

### Tests

```
# Basic positive test
$ ingroup -v wilma sudo && echo 'and therefore is cool'
wilma is in group sudo
and therefore is cool

# Basic negative test
$ ingroup -v wilma myprivateclub || echo 'sorry bout that'
wilma is not in group sudo
sorry bout that

# Test with hyphens in the group name
$ ingroup -v wilma systemd-journal
wilma is in group systemd-journal

# If the group does not exist, it's a negative
$ ingroup -v wilma somewronggroup
wilma is not in group somewronggroup
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with matching the entire line after iterating through each group name.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter username: " userName
read -p "Enter group: " groupName

groupCheck=$(id -nG $userName 2>/dev/null | awk -F " " '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' | grep -cx $groupName)

if [ $groupCheck = 1 ]; then
  echo $userName "is a member of" $groupName
else
  echo $userName "is not a member of" $groupName
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There are good solutions above, but I just want to reinforce that when using simple filter `grep -w "soughtword`can resolve. Sometimes there is no need to use  regex at all, it's already there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick effective way

```bash
check=`id $username` # Get the groups membership of the username

# Check if the groups membership contain the group
if [[ $check == *"$group"* ]]; then 
  echo $userName "is a member of" $group
else
  echo $userName "is not a member of" $group
fi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

### If you want to avoid "grep" or parsing

You may be surprised to discover that, even nowadays, this task is still completely un-trivial in scripts and commonly resolved parsing `id` with `grep`. Parsing is not efficient and can introduce unexpected broken corner-cases, for instance with the `root` user (that is not explicitly in any group), but also causing problems if a particular group/user is crafted with a dash in the name (`-`) or something else equally unpredictable, that may change from distribution to distribution.

So, you can avoid `id ... | grep ...` or similar. Instead:

### Alternative: Design a Unix Permission Check

Instead of checking if the current user is in a particular group, what about checking if the current user can **really** perform a particular action?

Example:

```bash
if [ -w /home/customers ]; then
    echo "You are authorized (I checked you can write)"
else
    echo "You are NOT authorized :-("
    echo "Join the group 'customers' please."
    echo "This incident will be reported."
    echo "Your current user is:"
    id
fi
```

This is just an example and can be bomb-proof, as long as you have a filename (or a directory) that is **not** writable by unknown people, but is **at least** writable by the group `customers`.

Example permissions:

- `/home/customers`
- owned by `root:customers`
- permissions `775`

Again, the file can be whatever, a file or a directory. Just use your Unix skills to design a file/directory (empty or not) that is **not** writable by anybody, but it's **at least** writable by that **group**. Accordingly to your real-world needs in that path, you may want to tune the "others" permission (last octet). So to have `755` if others should enter in that directory, or `770` if the directory should be locked down to others.

THAT FILE/DIRECTORY MUST **NOT** BE A STUPID `777` - THAT MEANS THAT EVERYONE CAN WRITE IT, SO THE CHECK WOULD BE ALWAYS TRUE FOR EVERYBODY. THIS IS NONSENSE.

Have fun with a secure and efficient way to check for permissions.

Additional documentation for file/directory permissions in Bash:

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html

### Additional notes

Note that the question is assuming a particular non-portable environment with a specific group called `customers`. That is the reason why I suggest this solution based on a related directory `/home/customers` - that the user very probably already has in place. But indeed do not adopt this solution as-is in a general-purpose script to be executed on every citizen of the world since they may have not that directory, and it's nonsense to be created ad-hoc for just this test. Anyway, in general, this is still useful and widely adopted. Look at the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard. There are plenty of files with dedicated groups that are writable only by that group to write on a particular media, device, serial port, etc. So this answer is still generally relevant to understand how to do things, if your priority is security and stability. So you can check for `test -w /dev/something` to know if the user can use that device, etc. Take inspiration:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard