# Check group membership for a Linux user using Java

Tags: java, linux, usergroups

Hi I can't figure out how to verify if a user belong to one o more group under Linux os using  java 7 nio library.

Can anyone help me about this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431285/bash-check-if-a-user-is-in-a-group Use this along with a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). I don't think there's a way to do this just with Java code.

Comment: Do the user which is going to run the program has read access to `/etc/group`?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo `/etc/group` is usually world-readable.

Comment: Your two options are basically to call out to the `groups` command (easiest by far) or wrap JNA around the POSIX or PAM calls.

Comment: What does NIO have to do with it?

Comment: I had used ProcessBuilder for this step and I lunch exec on "groups user" but I think this way is not very nice. Maybe Pablo's solution is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to read the file `/etc/group`.

I have developed a class to easily query this file:

```
public class UserInfo {

    public UserInfo() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        this.group2users = new HashMap<>();

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(groupsFilePath);
        BufferedReader groupsReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        while(groupsReader.ready())
        {
            try
            {
                String line = groupsReader.readLine();
                String [] tokens = line.split(":");
                String groupName = tokens[0];
                Set<String> users = group2users.get(groupName);
                if(users == null)
                {
                    users = new HashSet<String>();
                    group2users.put(groupName, users);
                }
                if(tokens.length>3)
                {
                    for(String uStr: tokens[3].split(","))
                        users.add(uStr);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { continue; }
        }
        groupsReader.close();
        fileReader.close();
    }

    public boolean belongs2group(String user, String group)
    {
        Set<String> groupRef = group2users.get(group);
        if(groupRef == null) return false;
        return groupRef.contains(user);
    }

    private String groupsFilePath = "/etc/group";
    private Map<String, Set<String>> group2users;

}
```

This code maps the `/etc/group` file and keep a map of groups-their users set.
I have developed just one query method (`belongs2group`) but it is fairly easy to add methods to list all groups and/or all users.

This code is written using the old-fashioned-mainstream java io-api but I think it can be easily adapted to nio. Let me know if you need me to complete that step.

Comment: Tnx very much for your answer, I try to trasform it under nio lib and give u a feedback.

Comment: /etc/group is not the only source of the information about group membership. Do not forget  about nis/ldap/pam, please.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that reading local `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group` could be good idea, because nis/ldap/ipa/pam can introduce other sources of infromation about group membership.
So, it depends on you environment and some other details. E.g.:

**Groups for logged in (current) user**

```
  com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixSystem().getGroups()
```

**Hadoop**

```
  org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getBestUGI(null,"root").getGroupNames()
```

**If neither is you case**

You can create jna wrapper for [getgroups(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setgroups.2.html).

Or *improve* [UnixSystem](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.security.auth/share/classes/com/sun/security/auth/module/UnixSystem.java) and [`Java_com_sun_security_auth_module_UnixSystem_getUnixInfo`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.security.auth/unix/native/libjaas/Unix.c)  from jdk to take user id/name parameter.

Or rewrite some implementation of `org.apache.hadoop.security.GroupMappingServiceProvider` interface to not depend on hadoop environment.