# Enumerating a user's groups in Java

Tags: java, linux

In a stored procedure in DB2, I need to look up information about user-groups. DB2 does not have built-in functionality for this, so it seems I need to write a user-defined function or user-defined procedure for this. In practice, that has to be written Java.

So, in Java: How do I query which groups a user is member of, as seen from the operating system? Alternatively: Given a group name, get a list of group member usernames.

The approach must work on Linux (it would be nice if it were operating system agnostic, but that's not important).

The approach must respect whatever authorization integrations are configured in the operating system. In other words: If the operating system has been set up to use SSSD for user authorization, then the Java code should not rely on being able to find group memberships in the /etc/group.

So I want to be able to do the equivalent of the "id USERNAME" or "getent group GROUPNAME" Linux shell command from Java. Python has the "grp" module for this kind of task, but I haven't found something similar for Java, yet.

Preferably, the solution should rely on as few external libraries as possible. It would be best, if it only rely on APIs which are part of a reasonably modern JRE.

Comment: Sorry, wrong language.  Java attempts to be platform independent, so it does not concern itself with such things.   Google may turn up somebody who has implemented something which will help you.

Comment: You can run a system command from Java and parse the output.

Comment: John: I need to use Java for this.
Please don't tell me to google; there's a reason why I asked the question: google didn't turn up anything useful.

Comment: You described your task, but you did not state a problem. What is the problem? Please show the code where you are having trouble.

Comment: Henry: Thanks; I may have to resort to that. But I'm curious to know, whether Java has a more "clean" way to do it.

Comment: I don't know what you expect. Henry gave you a correct answer. Java is platform independent, so there is no "clean" way to do platform specific operations, except NIO and maybe some libs as grp for Python.

Comment: Bevor: I'm no Java expert, that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: By "clean" I guess I'm talking about how JDNI can be used to perform DNS lookups (even though JDNI seems somewhat overdesigned for basic DNS lookups), instead of calling out to the "host" utility, etc. 
Maybe there's someting similar for group membership lookups?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check group membership for a Linux user using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22845489/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "clean" to way to do this in Java.  Java does not have any standard APIs for enumerating a user's groups.  Your options would be:

- implement a native library wrapper that called the `getgroups` C library method, and then call it from Java via JNI or JNA
- use java.lang.Process to call an external program to get the information
- query LDAP or Kerberos / AD or JNDI from Java

The last one only works if the system uses LDAP / Kerberos / JNDI and you have the appropriate credentials, schema configs and so on.  These make this possibly the hardest approach ... and *in practice* just as non-portable as the other approaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the precise answer. I may have to resort to writing in C rather than Java, then -- although I would prefer a managed language, and although it entails a number of problems with regards to deployment.