# Find group names of current user

Tags: java, linux, active-directory

I'm trying to find the `groups` of the active user from a Java application running on Linux.

I'm aware that I could run something like the `id` shell command and parse its output in Java, but I've also stumbled upon the [UnixSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/jaas/spec/com/sun/security/auth/module/UnixSystem.html) class, which gives me an array of all gids the current user belongs to. Is there a way to find out which group names match to these gids?

Since the groups are assigned to the user by being a memboer of a Microsoft Active Directory, parsing /etc/group will NOT help.

Comment: The first idea here is to read `/etc/group` file where you have mapping with id and group name

Comment: Sadly, /etc/group is not useful here since the user is an AD user and has its groups assigned by AD.

Comment: You'd likely need to use an LDAP client to connect to Active Directory and query the user information to find their groups using `javax.naming.*` and `javax.naming.directory.*`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check group membership for a Linux user using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22845489/608639)

Comment: @Fang - You can try something like `ldapsearch` as shown in the example here: https://serverfault.com/a/737519/432467