# Toggle for adding a user to and removing the user from sudo group?

Tags: bash, centos, sudo, sudoers

I know how to add users to the sudo group or how to remove him/her from it:

```
sudo usermod -aG wheel $1 # $1 represents the username as an argument passed to the command
sudo gpasswd -d $1 wheel
```

How do I make it a toggle? If the user is in the sudo group, I'd remove it from the group, otherwise add it. It's useful for temporarily granting sudo privileges.

Comment: `if groups "$1" | cut -d: -f2 | grep -F wheel ; then echo good; else echo bad; fi` ?

Comment: `if getent group wheel | grep -Fq "$1"; then sudo gpasswd ...; else sudo usermod ... ; fi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `if` that checks whether the user is currently in the group.
See also [Check if a user is in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18431285/6770384), from which I borrowed [this check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28926650/6770384).

```
if [[ " $(id -Gn "$1") " == *" wheel "* ]]; then
    sudo gpasswd -d "$1" wheel
else
    sudo usermod -aG wheel "$1 "
fi
```